# JOGL GLCanvas resizing fails after a setVisible() call from another frame

Tags: java, eclipse, jframe, jogl, glcanvas

I have a problem with JOGL. I`d like to create two windows. One with a GLCanvas and another one with something else.
Every time I call setVisible() of another frame before calling setVisible() of the frame where I added
the canvas. When resizing I get only a white window.

```
GLProfile profile = GLProfile.get(GLProfile.GL2);
GLCapabilities capabilities = new GLCapabilities(profile);
GLCanvas canvas = new GLCanvas(capabilities);
JFrame f2 = new JFrame();
f2.setSize(500, 500);
JFrame f = new JFrame();
f.setSize(500, 500);
canvas.setVisible(true);
f.add(canvas);
f2.setVisible(true);
f.setVisible(true);
f.pack();
```

If I change

```
f2.setVisible(true);
f.setVisible(true);
```

to

```
f.setVisible(true);
f2.setVisible(true);
```

everything works and I get my black window even after rescaling it.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Which version of JOGL do you use? Don't tell me "I use the latest", indicate precisely which version you use, follow these instructions to fill a bug report: http://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Jogl_FAQ#Bugreports_.26_Testing

Comment: Oh, I will test it with a new Version I use "2.2.4" at the moment. Thank you for your help.

Comment: The latest version is (currently, April 1st 2015) the version 2.3.1.

Comment: Ok, I tested it with 2.3.1 and got the same issue but it was a bit more random. (it fails even sometimes in the second case, first f.setVisible() and then f2.setVisible())

Comment: Ok. Therefore, you should fill a bug report.

Comment: You're welcome. We'll take your report into consideration. I hope that there is only something trivial to modify.

Comment: Sorry for my dumb question. Do you use an animator? Please look at my example here: https://gist.github.com/gouessej/3420e2b6f632efdddf98

Comment: In this example I didn't use one but I got the effect with one too.

Comment: Why do you use GL and GL2 in your code? You could use GL2 instead of GL. Or is there a difference between the final values?

Comment: Have you filled a bug report? Using the most general GL interface is a good practice as it allows your code to work on more machines. Imagine that you use GL2 instead of GL2ES2, your code will work only on GL2 whereas it might work on ES2 too. Using GL2 everywhere is a bad practice inspired by some APIs with a debatable design that are rarely used to write some code common to OpenGL and OpenGL ES.